# How to use mysqli_real_escape_string to san an array parsed by json ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I have an ajax parsing an array

**jquery**

```
if (conceptName == "payall"){
var payall = confirm ("You are about paying for some items.");
if (payall == true ){
   var checkedB = new Array();
    $("input.NP:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
       checkedB.push($(this).attr("class"));
   });

   // ajax for sending the selected products array for the payment
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "ord/payforit.php",
      data: {checkedB:checkedB},
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(resultpay) {
                     alert (resultpay);

       } 
     });
  } else {
    alert ("Ok, Do you still wanna add items?");
  }
```

**php**

```
require "dbconnection.php";
$getarr = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["checkedB"]);  
echo json_encode ($getarr);
```

the array parses with no problem if I use $_POST["checkedB"] without sanitising, but with the above code I'll have

```
<br /> 
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in     <b>e/ru/ord/payforit.php</b> on    line <b>21</b><br />
null
```

what is so wrong with my code, I am sure that my DB connection is fine, there is no error with my picture upload that uses the same directory.

Please help me out here.

Appreciated.

Comment: so: what does it mean to sanitize an array?

Comment: :O don't you know what does sanitise mean ?????

Comment: I know precisely what it means. So, given a data structure like an Array, how would you *expect* it to be sanitized as a *String* for a database call?

Comment: You need to iterate through the array.

Comment: Why do you need to sanitize the value if you're encoding it with JSON? You only need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` if you're interpolating the value into a SQL query.

Comment: @Barmar its an important value being parsed, I want to be sure that its clean.

Comment: JSON is inherently clean.

Comment: The only purpose of `mysqli_real_escape_string` is to escape values that are being substituted into a SQL query. If you're echoing the value, you should use `htmlentities()` to sanitize if for HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate through an array and apply it to the values (and keys if you're handling post and get)

```
foreach ( $_POST["checkedB"] as $k=>$v ) {
    ${mysqli_real_escape_string( $db, $k )} = mysql_reali_escape_string( $db, $v );
}

echo $someKeyInArray;
```

Or to recompile an array

```
$array = array();
foreach ( $_POST["checkedB"] as $k=>$v ) {
    $array[mysqli_real_escape_string( $db, $k )] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db, $v );
}

echo $array['someKeyInArray'];
```

If your array model contains ***Multiple Arrays*** then you would need to utilize a function to properly iterate through all arrays, something like this *(not tested)*

```
function mysqli_escape_array( $arr, $db = false ) {
    if ( ! $db ) {
        return false;
    }
    $array = array();
    foreach ( $arr as $k=>$v ) {
        if ( is_array( $v ) ) {
            $array[mysqli_real_escape_string( $db, $k )] = mysqli_escape_array( $v, $db );
        } else {
            $array[mysqli_real_escape_string( $db, $k )] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db, $v );
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}

$array = mysqli_escape_array( $_POST['checkedB'], $db );

echo json_encode( $array );
```

Comment: You're calling `mysql` instead of `mysqli`, and you're missing the first argument.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` will default to the active connection if no DB is provided. At least it originally did since it's introduction.

Comment: He's not using `mysql_real_escape_string`, he's using `mysqli_real_escape_string`. mysqli doesn't default like mysql does.

Comment: **[It sure does](http://us2.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)** Edited with _right_ function.

Comment: the recompile an array worked for me, thanks, it will be appreciated if you could vote up my question too. Thanks again for your valuable reply.

Comment: @user3150692 Thanks, and I did vote you up. I also added a function method to sanitize multiple arrays in the master array if there is, or will be.

Answer (score 8):

You need to iterate over the array:

```
$getarr = array();
foreach($_POST['checkedB'] AS $val) {
    $getarr[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $val);
}
echo json_encode($getarr);
```

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in `checkedB`.

Comment: Your `_POST` is not an array then. Edit: That'd do ti.

Comment: Yes, because you felt the need to argue someone elses point and have them edit it, then post the same thing, with a level of exploitation.

Comment: How can my keys be exploited? I'm creating a numeric array.

Comment: This is true. I'm sorry for that. However, he then has a broken JSON that cannot be differed to be it's keys...

Comment: I'll admit that I'm ignoring the keys of the input array. But I'll bet anything its also a numeric array, not associative. It's very unusual to use associative arrays in $_POST.

Comment: That all depends on the functionality in question and the method in use. He could use names like 'apple' to refer an an array of apple types and ratings, sort of thing. moving on then to a orange.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the reply, I vote up your answer again, and your answer works perfectly, it's simple and useful, I don't like when minds go so complicated. I will be appreciated if you vote up my question too. Thanks again for your valuable reply.